# With the following information, can one identify which piece of hardware might be at fault for an unresponsive PC?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

So here's the background: I left my computer alone for a while, then came back to it. While I left it alone, it had gone to sleep. When I attempted to 'wake' it, turn it back on, my battery backup power bar - a back-UPS 750 - began to beep a single unbroken tone, loudly and piercingly. I'll admit I panicked a little and turned it off, then began unplugging particular peripherals and turning it back on, it was still emitting the single tone, turned it back off, unplugged something else, etc. (the smart move would have been to Google immediately what a single unbroken tone meant, that being that the power bar was over capacity).

Anyway, several on-off cycles later and after unplugging several peripherals, the long tone finally stops. I'm relieved, until I go to turn on my computer and it... does nothing. I tried turning it on with the power bar plugged into a different outlet, I tried turning it on with the computer itself plugged into a different outlet (no power bar), and I tried turning it on with a different power cord. I also reset the breakers just for fun. None of it worked, so we can conclude fairly definitively that the problem is internal to the computer, not external.

There are two obvious culprits; the motherboard and the PSU. Given that the failure was immediately preceded by an issue with the attached power bar, my inclination is to eye the PSU with greater suspicion. This is reinforced by the fact that the computer does NOTHING when the power button is pushed - often, in my experience, a motherboard or peripheral failure will result in the computer starting and then failing, or a beep from the motherboard, SOME kind of acknowledgement that the computer tried to do SOMETHING. In this case, there's just nothing. The PC could be classified as 'dead' currently.

Ultimately, my question is: given the above information, am I likely correct in my assumption that the PSU has experienced some kind of failure? Or am I simply living under the false hope that all I'll need to replace is a PSU and not an entire motherboard?

Comment: We have no way of knowing.  You will have to start replacing parts until you figure which part fail.  Purchase from a source that allows for returns when you determine the part in question isn't bad.  I would replace the PSU, Motherboard and CPU and return everything that wasn't broken.

Comment: Well, I'm not so much asking if we can KNOW, as I am asking if we could make a reasonable assumption based on the given information. Find a good place to start, in other words.

Comment: We cannot.  You are doing exactly what we would do, guess at which part.  Currently the information doesn't give us the ability to guess better than you.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely correct in your assumption that the PSU has experienced some kind of failure.

You may be living under the false hope that all you'll need to replace is the PSU and not the entire motherboard, as dying PSUs can kill things on their way down.

Comment: Since this is all speculation, it would probably be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you just unplug the PSU from the motherboard for a good 60seconds+ and replug it back and run computer again without UPS

Best case scenario - you're good to go after that.